# Do python functions ignore the data type of arguments passed in?

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

I wrote some code that lets the += operator be used on a tuple inside a function, yet won't let the same += operator work on the tuple outside of the function.

```
def append_to_sequence (myseq):
    myseq += (9, 9, 9)
    return myseq

tuple1 = (1, 2, 3)
tuple2 = append_to_sequence(tuple1)

print (tuple1) # prints (1, 2, 3)
print (tuple2) # prints (1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 9)
```

But the code below returns an invalid syntax error:

```
>>> tuple1 = (1, 2, 3)
>>> tuple2 = tuple1 += (9, 9, 9)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    tuple2 = tuple1 += (9, 9, 9)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'd have to write this to get the same effect as the append_to_sequence function above.

```
tuple1 = (1, 2, 3)
tuple2 = tuple1 + (9, 9, 9)
```

So it seems like the += operator is working on the tuple when it's passed into the function even though it wouldn't work on an immutable object outside of the function. I was just curious if python functions ignore the data type (or immutability?) of arguments passed in to allow more operators to work on them?

Comment: This has nothing to do with types. Assignment isn't an expression in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`tuple1 += (9, 9, 9)` is not a valid rvalue.  It's not about the types: this code sample also fails with invalid syntax:

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = a += b
```

If you run it in the python shell, you'll see that `a + b` evaluates to a value that is printed, but `a += b` does not.